# ElasticSearch - How can I do nested field aggregation with field aliases?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query a nested field's inner hits for cardinality, however it's not working for field aliases (where resellers.price is an alias). I'm using an elastic search example to show this

```
GET /products/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "resellers": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "resellers"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_prices": {
        "cardinality": { "field": "resellers.price" } 
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your field mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "resellers": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "cost": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "price": {
            "type": "alias",
            "path": "resellers.cost"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "resellers": {
    "cost": 200
  }
}
{
  "resellers": {
    "cost": 100
  }
}
{
  "resellers": {
    "cost": 200
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "resellers": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "resellers"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_prices": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "resellers.price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "resellers": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "unique_prices": {
        "value": 2
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @roat please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @roat can you please reply back to my previous comments ?